# vaio wifi does not seem

Tags: wireless, vaio

I have Sony Vaio svF1532YST model notebook and I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it.I couldn't connect the wifi and entered "rfkill list all" command to the terminal but interestingly my wifi adapter didn't seem.I only got these:

```
 - 0: nfc0: NFC
             Soft blocked:no
             Hard blocked:no 
   1: hci0:Bluetooth
             Soft blocked:no
             Hard blocked:no
```

Thanks for your interest

Comment: Add the results from `lsusb` and `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`  I would say that the correct driver(module) isn't loaded for your wifi

Comment: Doesnt seem to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wifi should work after running this command in terminal `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

If you have no connection to the internet the bcmwl-kernel-source can be found on the DVD/USB you installed from in /pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/

Answer (score 0):

@Jeremy31
My results are here:

```
lsusb
```

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b42d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0489:e062 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

`entlspci -nnk|grep -iA2 <br/>` 
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e071]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 
 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device [104d:90be]

```
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```